# Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $x^3 + 2x + 1$, and let $g(x) = x^3 + x + 1$. Does $g(x)$ have a root in $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Problem: Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $f(x) = x^3 + 2x + 1$, and let $g(x) = x^3 + x + 1$.  Does $g(x)$ have a root in $K$?

My Attempt: I have proved that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are irreducible and found that their discriminates are not squares, so the Galois group is $S_3$ for both of them. Then it has to be that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] = 2$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}]$. So, $\alpha$ is a square root of something, but I am stuck here. I don't know what to do. The discriminant is not in the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, so we cannot work with it. And the formula for the roots of cubic polynomial gives alpha as a sum of two very complicated cubic roots.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something easy, but why is it $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$?

Comment: Wait, $\alpha$ is the root of an irreducible cubic polynomial. It follows immediately that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}] = 3$.

Comment: One could write $\beta = b_0 + b_1\alpha + b_2\alpha^2$, and then compute $\beta^3$ looking for either a contradiction or the rational numbers $b_0$, $b_1$, and $b_2$. Perhaps there is a more high-tech solution.

Comment: Suppose $\alpha$ has degree 3, then $\alpha^3$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$, then when you plug it in to $f(x)$ then $\alpha^3 + 2\alpha + 1$ cannot be equal to $0$ because $2 \alpha$ is the only element not in $\mathbb{Q}$ and it's not equal to $0$.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is of degree $3$ over $\mathbb Q$, it is most certainly not the case that $\alpha^3$ has to be in $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here’s an approach that is every bit as advanced as @BrunoJoyal’s, but goes at the question from an entirely different direction. And it is not complete, as you will see below.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of your $f$, and $\beta$ be a root of your $g$, let $K=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ and $L=\mathbb Q(\beta)$. The question is simply whether $K=L$, since both are cubic fields (from irreducibility of $f$ and of $g$) and if $\beta\in K$ then $L=\mathbb Q(\beta)\subset K$. Multiplicativity of degrees would then show equality.

Now, both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are units in their respective integer rings, and if the fields are the same, it must be that there are (small) integers $m$ and $n$ such that $\alpha^m=\beta^n$. The reason is that both $K$ and $L$ are cubic fields with only one real embedding and one complex. This follows from the fact that both polynomials cross the $x$-axis only once. The consequence for the groups of units is that each is of the form $\mathbb Z\oplus C_2$, where the second is just the cyclic group $\{\pm1\}$. Now, if I was very ambitious, I’d calculate the real roots of $f$ and $g$, and find the ratio of their logs. If this is not obviously a rational number, I’d be completely convinced that the two groups of units were incommensurable, and feel confident that the fields thus were different.

**EDIT**:

Here’s another approach that is just as advanced, but complete and not dubious. Look at the situation locally at the prime $3$. Since $f(x-1)=x^3-3x^2+6x-3$, Eisenstein, $K$ has just one prime above $3$, totally ramified. On the other hand, modulo $3$, we have $x^3+x+1=(x-1)(x^2+x-1)$, so that in $L$, $3$ splits into two primes, one of degree $1$ and one of degree $2$ with residue field extension degree $2$. That is, $L$ is unramified at $3$. So the fields are different, and therefore $\beta\notin K$.

Comment: Dear Prof. Lubin: this is great! It boils down to calculating a real number with high precision; at that point, there is no trace left of the initial problem! I wonder if one can say in advance how many digits of this real number one would need to compute to be sure that it is not rational. I suppose it might also happen that we are very unlucky, and that this number *is* rational, while $L\neq K$ still...

Comment: Being comparatively uneducated in more advanced number theory, I believe that a rational value is not possible, but this is a statement of faith. (p.s. please don’t call me Prof! Just “Lubin” will be perfectly fine, thank you.)

Comment: Dear Lubin: You are right. In this case, we have $\mathbf Q(\alpha^m) = K$ for each $m$, by comparing degrees. What I had in mind was the possibility for two different number fields to have commensurable regulators (for instance in the trivial case of two imaginary quadratic fields). But no funny business of the sort can happen here.

Answer (score 7):

The discriminant of $f$ is $-59$ and the discriminant of $g$ is $-31$. These two numbers are square-free, so they are actually the discriminants of the ring of integers of the corresponding number fields $K$ and $L=\mathbf Q[x]/g(x)$. Since $(31,59)=1$ it follows that $g$ has no root in $K$ (because $K$ ramifies only over the prime $59$, and $L$ ramifies only over the prime $31$).

*Suggestion for a more elementary approach*: pick an indeterminate element $y=u\alpha^2 + v\alpha + w \in K$, where $u,v,w \in \mathbf Q$. By calculating a linear dependence relation between $y^2, y$ and $1$, obtain a (not necessarily monic) polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbf Z[u,v,w][x]$ such that $p(y) = 0$. Then, calculate the [resultant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $p$ and $g$ by writing it as the determinant of the appropriate [Sylvester matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix). This will give you a polynomial $R\in \mathbf Z[u,v,w]$. If you can prove that $R(a,b,c) \neq 0$  for all $(a,b,c) \in \mathbf Q$, it will follow that $f$ has no root in $K$.

Comment: This is precisely the proof that I wanted to give, but in view of the fact that OP would clearly not be convinced by an argument involving something (s)he knows nothing of, I wonder whether there is a more elementary argument.

Comment: Dear Prof. @Lubin: I agree that a more elementary solution would be much more suitable. I am posting this mostly for the pleasure of anyone who might enjoy reading it. Best regards,

Comment: Dear Prof. @Lubin: I have suggested a more elementary approach, which might or might not work in this particular case. Perhaps it can be improved?

Comment: The question came from Artin's Algebra text and comes from the chapter on Galois Theory and the section on cubic equations, which does not mention the Sylvester matrix.

Comment: Dear @willkurada: Perhaps Artin had a specific approach in mind. There are certainly many ways to do this, but I do not know what Artin intended. All the best,

Comment: Okay, I will keep trying, thanks for your help!

Comment: Dear Bruno, the advanced solution you post looks interesting. I know nothing about ramification over the primes in algebraic number fields (but intending to learn soon). Would reading books like Neukirch's _Algebraic Number Theory_ would give me the tools you used in your solution? (Sorry for off-topic question)

Comment: Dear @Prism: Yes, Neukrich's book would definitely provide you with the right arsenal (and a lot more). Personally, I recommend D. Marcus' *Number Fields* for a very down to earth introduction to algebraic number theory (if you can get past the pre-LaTeX formatting).

Comment: Thank you for the advice :) I will go with Marcus' book (I have seen it recommended by others as well).

Answer (score 2):

For good measure, here is a solution closer to what's in Artin's Algebra.

As Bruno noted, the discriminants are $-59,-31$. These two are not squares, so by Galois Theory for Cubics (16.8.5), the splitting fields $L_f,L_g$ both have degree $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, with Galois group $S_3$. If $g(x)$ had a root in $K$, then it splits completely in $K$ by the Splitting Theorem (16.3.2), hence $L_f \cong L_g$ since both are of degree $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since the Galois group is $S_3$, there should be one intermediate field of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, but we have two, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-59})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-31})$, a contradiction.